# Memsql connection via keytab

Tags: database, authentication, jdbc, singlestore, keytab

We have application which connects via user name from white listed ip. Now we want to change this authentication mechanism with keytab file.

We have system user keytab and we want to connect to memsql cluster from our java application via an existing keytab.

How can we achieve this? Any github link or step by step guide would be awesome.

Cheers!
Sandip

Answer (score 0):

Is this for SingleStore self-hosted or cloud ?

If I understand correctly keytab is for Kerberos Authentication ? SingleStore fully support that, have you checked this documentation page : https://docs.singlestore.com/db/v7.8/en/security/authentication/kerberos-authentication/configuring-singlestoredb-for-kerberos-authentication.html